# Generating username with given information from the user

Tags: java

Hi Im Can Somebody help me with my program ?
my professor ask us to do a program that will get information from the user and generate a 6 letter username from the lastname and firstname of the user. 
the first 3 letters of the user name is the first 3 letters of the firstname and the other 3 is the last 3 letters of the lastname of the user. and we need to test it by log-in module
to test if the username and password are match on the generated username and user inputted password

As far as im doing i cant find a answer on this and our professor didn't teach us about this this and im struggling right now.

this is my program right now>>>

```
public static InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
public static BufferedReader i = new BufferedReader(r);

public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{

    String Lname,Fname,Mi;
    int age,bday;
    float pass;

    System.out.print("Enter Last Name: ");
    Lname=i.readLine();
    System.out.print("Enter First Name: ");
    Fname=i.readLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Middle Name: ");
    Mi=i.readLine();
    System.out.print("Age: ");
    age=Integer.parseInt(i.readLine());
    System.out.print("Birthday (MM/DD/YY) :");
    bday=Integer.parseInt(i.readLine());
    System.out.println("Password Must Be A 4-6 Digit Combination");
    System.out.print("Enter Password : ");
    pass=Float.parseFloat(i.readLine());

    System.out.println("Please Wait While Generating Your UserName");
    for(int j=0;j<=35;j++)
    {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            System.out.print("*");
    }


}
```

Can Somebody Help Me Please....

Comment: look at [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just:

```
String username = FName.substring(0,3) + LName.substring(LName.length() - 3, LName.length());
```

***You should probably check that FName and LName have a minimum length of 3 characters, or you will get an exception***

Comment: can you help me pleas ?